# Debian based guests sometimes boot into UEFI shell qemu

Tags: debian, qemu, uefi, libvirt

My host runs Debian 12 and is used as a hypervisor using QEMU and libvirt. I have several Debian based server VMs and they almost always boot into UEFI shell instead of normally. I still can boot by typing exit and navigating to grub's efi file but it is quite annoying since other guests (including a Windows VM) doesn't suffer from this. Any idea how to fix this?

Relevant section of libvirt XML:

```
  <os firmware="efi">
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-7.2">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state="off"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on"/>
```

Comment: Have you considered the issue may be with the guest itself? i.e. perhaps a grub issue - though "almost always" suggests this is an intermittent issue (albeit almost always an issue) which makes it that much harder to diagnose - does this occur if you reboot the guest, i.e. it's not only when the host itself starts up?

Comment: I guess the issue is that some Debian guests are not properly registering a boot entry. I will try to reinstall grub in the affected guests.

Comment: Well that turned out to be exactly that: For some unknown reason the boot entry disappeared in affected guests which led `qemu` to boot into an EFI shell. Reinstalling grub fixes the issue...